# conditional counter with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to apply odd and even classes to "parent" rows. I want to know if there's a way to only increase the counter if it's a parent.
Is there a way to do this inline? The way I've set it up doesn't seem to increment the counter.

```
...
<tbody ng-init="parentCount=0">
  <tr ng-repeat="value in finalArr"
      ng-class={'parentRow': value.isParent, 'childRow': !value.isParent}
      parentCount="{value.isParent ? parentCount = parentCount + 1}"
      ...
  >
    <td>
      id: {{ value.isParent ? parentCount : '' }}
    </td>
    ...
 </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
...
```

Comment: I suspect the code inside your `parentCount` attribute is not being run. Try replacing `parentCount="..."` with `ng-init="..."`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

As pointed out by Daniel, I misunderstood the problem. The `value` object could be a parent or a child and you want to only increment the counter if it is a parent. Here is a solution that I can think of:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.counter = {
    parentCount: 0
  }
  
  $scope.incrementParent = function (item) {
    if (item.isParent) {
      $scope.counter.parentCount++
    }
    return $scope.counter.parentCount
  }
  
  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'a', isParent: true},
    {name: 'b', isParent: true},
    {name: 'c', isParent: false},
    {name: 'd', isParent: false},
    {name: 'e', isParent: true},
    {name: 'f', isParent: true},
  ]
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items"  ng-init="count = incrementParent(item)">
    {{item.name}} - the parent count: {{item.isParent ? count : 'is a child'}}
  </div>
  
</div>
```

If you want to do it inline, you can compress the `incrementParent` function into one line (though I don't think it is very readable):

`<div ng-repeat="item in items"  ng-init="count = (item.isParent ? (counter.parentCount = counter.parentCount + 1) : counter.parentCount)">`

Note:

I put the `parentCount` to an object because `ng-repeat` will create a new scope for each item. If you directly assign to `parentCount` in the template you will be modifying the child scope not the parent.

For each item we create a snapshot of the current `parentCount` value and assign it to a variable `count` in `ng-init`. If you directly use `counter.parentCount` for each item it will not work because they will all be the same value after the loop ends.

**Original:**

In the `ng-repeat` scope, there is an `$index` property available that can be used as the counter (just that it starts from 0). AngularJS maintains it so you don't have to increment it yourself. It's better just use that one.

Regards to why your counter is not incremented, <s>`"{value.isParent ? parentCount = parentCount + 1}"` doesn't seem to be valid JavaScript syntax (for ternary operator you need the `:` part). I suspect it will throw and AngularJs will catch it and just ignore it.</s> 
The `parentCount` attribute you added to `td` is not recognized by Angular. Angular only accept registered directives or bindings, not random attributes.

Comment: Checking if `"{value.isParent ? parentCount++ : null}"` solves the issue might be worth it.

Comment: I don't think he's after `$index` because `value.isParent` hints towards another intended usage. It's just to get an aggregate count of parents (= all minus children).

Comment: @DanielF got it. You are right. I'll need to update the answer after I experiment with it.